# In GLSurface, KeyListener does not work with Soft Keyboard from InputMethod?

Tags: android, opengl-es, keylistener

I hava a GLSurface, a KeyListener and TouchListener, I added the listeners to the suface and when the user click on the screen open the soft keyboard using this code:

```
   InputMethodManager inputMethod = (InputMethodManager)((Activity)game).getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   inputMethod.showSoftInput(game.getGraphics().getView(), 0);
```

"game.getGraphics().getView()" returns the GLSurface. This code is working.
But when I press any key on soft keyboard, the listener does not receive any event. Why?
How can I fix it?
I know the OnKeyListener does not necessary receive event from software, but what I need to do?